# Jhipster relationship not reflected in Angular Frontend

Tags: angular, spring, jhipster

I created an application with three entities:

**Employee**

```
    {
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "name",
      "fieldType": "String"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "designation",
      "fieldType": "String"
    }
  ],
  "relationships": [
    {
      "relationshipName": "testTeam",
      "otherEntityName": "testTeam",
      "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
      "otherEntityField": "id",
      "ownerSide": true,
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "employee"
    }
  ],
  "service": "serviceImpl",
  "dto": "no",
  "jpaMetamodelFiltering": false,
  "readOnly": false,
  "pagination": "pagination",
  "name": "Employee",
  "changelogDate": "20210803173926"
}
```

**Projects**

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "name",
      "fieldType": "String"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "projectId",
      "fieldType": "String"
    }
  ],
  "relationships": [
    {
      "relationshipName": "testTeam",
      "otherEntityName": "testTeam",
      "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
      "otherEntityField": "id"
    }
  ],
  "service": "serviceImpl",
  "dto": "no",
  "jpaMetamodelFiltering": false,
  "readOnly": false,
  "pagination": "pagination",
  "name": "Projects",
  "changelogDate": "20210803174304"
}
```

**Team**

```
{
  "fields": [],
  "relationships": [
    {
      "relationshipName": "employee",
      "otherEntityName": "employee",
      "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
      "ownerSide": false,
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "testTeam"
    },
    {
      "relationshipName": "projects",
      "otherEntityName": "projects",
      "relationshipType": "one-to-many",
      "otherEntityRelationshipName": "testTeam"
    }
  ],
  "service": "serviceImpl",
  "dto": "no",
  "jpaMetamodelFiltering": false,
  "readOnly": false,
  "pagination": "pagination",
  "name": "TestTeam",
  "changelogDate": "20210803174127"
}
```

Since there is a one to many relationship between **Team** and **Projects** and a many to many relationship between **Team** and **Employee**, my assumption is that the **Team** front end will show the list of User and Projects related to it. Instead the table is completely blank and the Create Team button shows only the ID of the **Team** table:

[image: no entry for project and team]

[image: no provision for entry]

1. What change do I need to make in order to show the list of Employees and Projects related to the Team in the frontend list?
2. I want to be able to select the list of users and Projects to be linked to the Team from the Team entry/edit page. How do I do that?

EDIT: TestTeam component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ITestTeam } from '../test-team.model';

import { ASC, DESC, ITEMS_PER_PAGE, SORT } from 'app/config/pagination.constants';
import { TestTeamService } from '../service/test-team.service';
import { TestTeamDeleteDialogComponent } from '../delete/test-team-delete-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-test-team',
  templateUrl: './test-team.component.html',
})
export class TestTeamComponent implements OnInit {
  testTeams?: ITestTeam[];
  isLoading = false;
  totalItems = 0;
  itemsPerPage = ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
  page?: number;
  predicate!: string;
  ascending!: boolean;
  ngbPaginationPage = 1;

  constructor(
    protected testTeamService: TestTeamService,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    protected router: Router,
    protected modalService: NgbModal
  ) {}

  loadPage(page?: number, dontNavigate?: boolean): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const pageToLoad: number = page ?? this.page ?? 1;

    this.testTeamService
      .query({
        page: pageToLoad - 1,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        sort: this.sort(),
      })
      .subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<ITestTeam[]>) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers, pageToLoad, !dontNavigate);
        },
        () => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.onError();
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.handleNavigation();
  }

  trackId(index: number, item: ITestTeam): number {
    return item.id!;
  }

  delete(testTeam: ITestTeam): void {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(TestTeamDeleteDialogComponent, { size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' });
    modalRef.componentInstance.testTeam = testTeam;
    // unsubscribe not needed because closed completes on modal close
    modalRef.closed.subscribe(reason => {
      if (reason === 'deleted') {
        this.loadPage();
      }
    });
  }

  protected sort(): string[] {
    const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.ascending ? ASC : DESC)];
    if (this.predicate !== 'id') {
      result.push('id');
    }
    return result;
  }

  protected handleNavigation(): void {
    combineLatest([this.activatedRoute.data, this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap]).subscribe(([data, params]) => {
      const page = params.get('page');
      const pageNumber = page !== null ? +page : 1;
      const sort = (params.get(SORT) ?? data['defaultSort']).split(',');
      const predicate = sort[0];
      const ascending = sort[1] === ASC;
      if (pageNumber !== this.page || predicate !== this.predicate || ascending !== this.ascending) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.ascending = ascending;
        this.loadPage(pageNumber, true);
      }
    });
  }

  protected onSuccess(data: ITestTeam[] | null, headers: HttpHeaders, page: number, navigate: boolean): void {
    this.totalItems = Number(headers.get('X-Total-Count'));
    this.page = page;
    if (navigate) {
      this.router.navigate(['/test-team'], {
        queryParams: {
          page: this.page,
          size: this.itemsPerPage,
          sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.ascending ? ASC : DESC),
        },
      });
    }
    this.testTeams = data ?? [];
    this.ngbPaginationPage = this.page;
  }

  protected onError(): void {
    this.ngbPaginationPage = this.page ?? 1;
  }
}
```

TestTeam component html

```
<div>
  <h2 id="page-heading" data-cy="TestTeamHeading">
    <span>Test Teams</span>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <button class="btn btn-info mr-2" (click)="loadPage()" [disabled]="isLoading">
        <fa-icon icon="sync" [spin]="isLoading"></fa-icon>
        <span>Refresh List</span>
      </button>

      <button
        id="jh-create-entity"
        data-cy="entityCreateButton"
        class="btn btn-primary jh-create-entity create-test-team"
        [routerLink]="['/test-team/new']"
      >
        <fa-icon icon="plus"></fa-icon>
        <span> Create a new Test Team </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </h2>

  <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>

  <jhi-alert></jhi-alert>

  <div class="alert alert-warning" id="no-result" *ngIf="testTeams?.length === 0">
    <span>No testTeams found</span>
  </div>

  <div class="table-responsive" id="entities" *ngIf="testTeams && testTeams.length > 0">
    <table class="table table-striped" aria-describedby="page-heading">
      <thead>
        <tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="ascending" [callback]="loadPage.bind(this)">
          <th scope="col" jhiSortBy="id"><span>ID</span> <fa-icon icon="sort"></fa-icon></th>
          <th scope="col" jhiSortBy="hnap"><span>Hnap</span> <fa-icon icon="sort"></fa-icon></th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let testTeam of testTeams; trackBy: trackId" data-cy="entityTable">
          <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/test-team', testTeam.id, 'view']">{{ testTeam.id }}</a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ testTeam.hnap }}</td>
          <td class="text-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button
                type="submit"
                [routerLink]="['/test-team', testTeam.id, 'view']"
                class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                data-cy="entityDetailsButton"
              >
                <fa-icon icon="eye"></fa-icon>
                <span class="d-none d-md-inline">View</span>
              </button>

              <button
                type="submit"
                [routerLink]="['/test-team', testTeam.id, 'edit']"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                data-cy="entityEditButton"
              >
                <fa-icon icon="pencil-alt"></fa-icon>
                <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Edit</span>
              </button>

              <button type="submit" (click)="delete(testTeam)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-cy="entityDeleteButton">
                <fa-icon icon="times"></fa-icon>
                <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Delete</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="testTeams && testTeams.length > 0">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <jhi-item-count [params]="{ page: page, totalItems: totalItems, itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage }"></jhi-item-count>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <ngb-pagination
        [collectionSize]="totalItems"
        [(page)]="ngbPaginationPage"
        [pageSize]="itemsPerPage"
        [maxSize]="5"
        [rotate]="true"
        [boundaryLinks]="true"
        (pageChange)="loadPage($event)"
      ></ngb-pagination>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the "Test Team" Component HMTL & TS code?

Comment: Chosing "dto": "yes" would make it easier on the backend fort you to modify manually generated code.

Comment: @matsch I've updated the question with the codes

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML-File you show, you need to add the wanted columns.

For example:

```
<th scope="col" jhiSortBy="Project"><span>Project</span> <fa-icon icon="sort"></fa-icon></th>
....

<td>{{ testTeam.project }}</td>
```

You will only be able to call the Project and Employees if you make sure, that they are set in the model of TestTeam. Usually you can find the model under `shared/model/testTeam.model.ts`

This is only the Frontend part. If this does not help you, you maybe should try to follow a step by step tutorial for Angular and JHipster.